# facebook comments are not shown its whole list in phone gap

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

i'm trying to put Facebook comments into my phonegap app on iOS using facebook cordova sdk.
i've already included Facebook_js_sdk.js and cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js. 
also, i added below code right after start of body tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ko_KR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and put below code where to be displayed

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

however, Facebook comments plugin always shows only a comment and HALF(it isn't fully loaded) when run the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try add this to your Css:

```
.fb_ltr { min-height:100%; !important; }
```

or

```
.fb_ltr { min-height:300px; !important; }
```

the first works for me eventhoug % height shouldent.